# earthengine: correct max value to plot RGB of Sentinell 2?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, visualisation, rgb

I would like to display the RGB true colors of a Sentinel Image in Earth Engine. I understand that I should adjust the parameter `max` in `Map.addLayer(..., {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 7000});` given that color bands are not in [0,255], but instead in [0,10000] ( based on the documentation [page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR), column `scale` is 0.0001) and this related [Stack question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291408/trying-to-display-sentinel-2-imagery-in-google-earth-engine-code-working-but-di).

But if I set `max: 10000`, I get basically a black image. If I set to the maximum value I find in my zone of interest (7000), I still get a very dark image. I found that to obtain a pleasing image, I should have a value of 1500...

What is happening? Why is setting the theoretical true range `max:10000` of my pixels giving me a super dark image? I need to understand this as when I export to another software (R), I won't be able to set `max:1500` (R will complain about values above the given max).

###### Example code

https://code.earthengine.google.com/650ed12224d6006ac1e9f992c3292d38

```
// select Zone of interest
var aoi1 =     ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-53.9, -11.29706], [-53.9, -11.52523],
          [-53.6, -11.52523], [-53.6, -11.29706]]]);
var aoi2 =     ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-53.5, -11.29706], [-53.5, -11.52523],
                                      [-53.2, -11.52523], [-53.2, -11.29706]]]);
var aoi3 =     ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-53, -11.29706], [-53, -11.52523],
          [-52.7, -11.52523], [-52.7, -11.29706]]]);




// Sentinell 
var Senti = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED").
  filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:id", "COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED/20220123T135109_20220123T135107_T22LBN"))
  
  
//Max values in band?
var maxBand = Senti.first().select(["B4", "B3", "B2"]).reduceRegion({reducer: 'max',geometry: aoi3, maxPixels: 1e10,})
print(maxBand)


// Plot
Map.centerObject(aoi2)

Map.addLayer(Senti.first().clip(aoi1), {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 7000}, 'image');
Map.addLayer(Senti.first().clip(aoi2), {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 3000}, 'image');
Map.addLayer(Senti.first().clip(aoi3), {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 1500}, 'image');
```

Comment: Are you planning to use that image in R to perform spectral analyses or calculate spectral indices? or you just want an image that can be visualized "pleasantly" in R?

Comment: just visualize "pleasantly" in R, so the scaling of the RGB values matters a lot.

Comment: But anyway, the R part is a detail, the main question is why setting the (supposedly) right max value of 10000 leads to a black image?

Comment: The max value *possible* is 10,000.  But a value of 10,000 would be an entire pixel reflecting 100% of all incoming sunlight.  Nothing does that.  Average albedo of the surface is 0.3, meaning you're only ever going to see ~30% of the sunlight reflected.  Include scattering, etc.  and reasonable values are in the 20% (2k) range.